# LibVLCSharp MediaPlayer marquee text for audio files?

Tags: libvlc, libvlcsharp, vlc-android

I've been messing around with LibVLCSharp and noticed that there is an option to display text when using the MediaPlayer. You can do this with SetMarqueeString (To set the text) and SetMarqueeInt (To enable the text to be shown).

This works great on video files. I discovered that this doesn't work at all if you are playing an audio file. Is this intentional, and if so, is there a way to display text when playing audio files?

Comment: I don't think there is since the marquee is blended into the video before rendering. for audio-only, what would it blend into?

Comment: @cube45 That makes sense. As a workaround, I just ended up making a toast notification instead. Thanks.